# when will move_base_msgs be catkinized?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my catkin package ,if I import "`move_base_msgs`",
then "`ImportError:No module named move_base_msgs`".

I know it is because it has not be catkinized,so I want to know when it will be completed.

My catkin is thirsty for this module.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59515/when-will--move_base_msgs-be-catkinized-?/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack is not yet catkinized. Do you have a package that depends on just the messages, but not the rest of that stack? I don't see any current catkin work in that repository: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-20**:
**For future readers**: note that this question was posted back in 2013. The move_base_msgs package was converted to catkin in the ROS Hydro distribution and is still basically the same for Indigo and Jade.